# Prove that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow\infty}ze^{\frac{1}{z}}=1$. Where $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{0}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried using the Laurent series for the function $ze^{\frac{1}{z}}$.
That is $z\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^nn!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{n-1}n!}$.
But here when $z\rightarrow\infty$ it gets infinity, not one as mentioned.

So I would like to know whether there is mistake that I have made in my calculation

Comment: Counterexample, let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ be the complex number $z=x+0i$ for $x>0$, then this limit is $\infty$.  This seems to be missing a condition.

Comment: The limit $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}ze^{1/z}$ will not be $1$. Are you sure you have typed everything  correctly?

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. It looks like there is a missing condition in the original question. So according to the way it is mentioned limit should be infinity, isn't it?

Comment: I think to get 1, you'd do L'Hopital's on $e^{1/z}/(1/z)$. But I'm not sure if that's justified.

Comment: @chhro Well... looks like your idea gives the result as 1.

Comment: @chhro So how should we get rid of this confussion?

Comment: If you do the change of variables $w=\frac{1}{z}$ this becomes $$\lim_{w \to 0} \frac{e^w}{w}$$ which is clearly $\infty$.